# if the user deny push notification permission, will my FCM listeners still be called?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

in iOS, there will be a pop up that will ask the user to accept or deny push notification permission.

if the user deny the permission or they set to not to display the push notification in the settings, will the FCM listeners to receive FCM message still be called? I mean this lines below.

in Android, if I disable to display the push notification in phone settings, then the listeners below will still be called. but unfortunately I can't test it for iOS since I don't have apple developer account yet at the moment

```
// to receive foreground message
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

});


// to receive background message
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Cloud Firestore | Requesting permission (Apple & Web)](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#requesting-permission-apple--web),

> On iOS, macOS & web, before FCM payloads can be received on your
> device, you must first ask the users permission. Android applications
> are not required to request permission.

So you need permission for the listeners to be called on iOS.